# Error 4866 when bulk inserting data from csv

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to load data from a csv file and keep getting these errors. Am I missing some params in the bulk insert script or do I need to modify the file before I attempt this?

```
Msg 4866, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 54. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.

Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.

Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1

Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Here's the script

```
BULK
INSERT BrowseNotes
FROM 'C:\Users\Jarek\browseNotes2.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
, ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Here are sample rows from the file, I delete out the first row before attempting to load. The rows end with ",/n". I've tried replacing /n with /r/n and removing the last comma. Still get the same error.

```
LoanType,Maturity,LoanClass,Borrower,LoanStatus,TimeLeftBeforeExpiration,MonthlyPayment,LoanMaturity,JobTenureYearsString,AmountToInvest,AmountMissingToClose,NumberOfPayments,Id,State,Type,Status,Aid,Amount,Duration,StartD,IntRate,Grade,Purpose,HousingStatus,JobTenure,Income,CreditClassId,City,UnfundedAmnt,Fico,OpenCreditLines,TotalCreditLines,Inq6Months,RevolvUtil,FundedPercentage,FundedAmount,EmpStatus,JobTitle,AppDate,AppAmount,Employer,DelinquentAmount,EarliestCreditLine,PubRecords,DTI,AppExpiration,LapStatus,IncomeVStatus,CreditReportD,RevolvCreditBal,AccntsNowDelinquent,Delinquencies2Yrs,MnthsSinceLastDelinquency,MnthsSinceLastRecord
PERSONAL,60,C4,1248804,INFUNDING,279589,344.62,Year5,8 years,0,625.0,60,1020047,PA,1,1,1248804,13775.0,60,2011-11-11 11:40:18,0.1527,C,debt_consolidation,MORTGAGE,96,50000.0,124,PHILADELPHIA,625.0,679-713,10,21,2,62.2,0.9565972222222222,13775.0,EMPLOYED,"Quality Assurance Manager",2011-11-11 11:40:18,14400.0,"J. Ambrogi Food Distribution",0.0,01/27/2003,0,23.14,2011-11-25 11:40:18,APPROVED_CR,NOT_REQUIRED,11/11/2011,22906.0,0,0,null,null,
PERSONAL,60,A5,1247389,INFUNDING,180323,289.94,Year5,3 years,0,1975.0,60,1018925,FL,1,1,1247389,12025.0,60,2011-11-10 08:05:52,0.089,A,house,MORTGAGE,36,150000.0,105,orange park,1950.0,750-779,9,25,0,62.9,0.8607142857142858,12050.0,EMPLOYED,"Project Manager",2011-11-10 08:05:52,14000.0,"Scientific Research Corp.",0.0,10/01/1984,0,14.02,2011-11-24 08:05:52,APPROVED_CR,VERIFIED,11/09/2011,43069.0,0,0,null,null,
```

Here's the table I'm trying to load to

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BrowseNotes](
    [LoanType] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [Maturity] [tinyint] NULL,
    [LoanClass] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [Borrower] [int] NULL,
    [LoanStatus] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [TimeLeftBeforeExpiration] [int] NULL,
    [MonthlyPayment] [smallmoney] NULL,
    [LoanMaturity] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [JobTenureYearsString] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [AmountToInvest] [smallmoney] NULL,
    [AmountMissingToClose] [smallmoney] NULL,
    [NumberOfPayments] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [State] [char](2) NULL,
    [Type] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Status] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Aid] [int] NULL,
    [Amount] [smallmoney] NULL,
    [Duration] [tinyint] NULL,
    [StartD] [datetime] NULL,
    [IntRate] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Grade] [char](1) NULL,
    [Purpose] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [HousingStatus] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [JobTenure] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Income] [money] NULL,
    [CreditClassId] [smallint] NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [UnfundedAmnt] [smallmoney] NULL,
    [Fico] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [OpenCreditLines] [tinyint] NULL,
    [TotalCreditLines] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Inq6Months] [tinyint] NULL,
    [RevolvUtil] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [FundedPercentage] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [FundedAmount] [smallmoney] NULL,
    [EmpStatus] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [JobTitle] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [AppDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [AppAmount] [money] NULL,
    [Employer] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [DelinquentAmount] [money] NULL,
    [EarliestCreditLine] [datetime] NULL,
    [PubRecords] [tinyint] NULL,
    [DTI] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [AppExpiration] [datetime] NULL,
    [LapStatus] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [IncomeVStatus] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [CreditReportD] [datetime] NULL,
    [RevolvCreditBal] [money] NULL,
    [AccntsNowDelinquent] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Delinquencies2Yrs] [tinyint] NULL,
    [MnthsSinceLastDelinquency] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [MnthsSinceLastRecord] [nvarchar](10) NULL
)
```

Comment: There's a comma after your first row of data which is probably causing the issue.

Comment: Every row ends with a comma. I've tried removing it before attempting the bulk insert, but kept getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure it's not trying to insert the header record with the column list?

Comment: I included the header record in my comment for clarity, but in the file I delete the first row before trying to bulk insert.

Comment: Why is this question getting down voted?  It looks like a fine question to me with script, error messages, table definition, and data.  What is it missing?

Comment: The data you provided gotta be different from what you really have. It worked perfectly on my sql-2008 WITHOUT the head row. However, it gave this error WITH the head row (Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 2 (Maturity).), but it inserted the other rows anyway.

Comment: Oh another thing is the comma at the end of the each row is incorporated into the last column as a string 'null,'

Answer (score 1):

What database is the table in? Try fully qualifying your table name i.e.

```
`mydb.dbo.BrowseNotes`
```

Though it certainly sounds like its not recognizing the ROWTERMINATOR .

Answer (score 1):

I know this is coming in waaaaaay late, but I figured out how to do this.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)

set @sql = '
BULK
INSERT BrowseNotes
FROM "C:\Users\Jarek\browseNotes2.csv"
WITH (
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ",",
  ROWTERMINATOR = "' + char(10) + '"
)'

exec(@sql)
GO
```

This script works by forcing the rowterminator to a literal '0A' (linefeed).  This works for both \r\n and \n terminated data.
I would also suggest using a pipe character (or anything *not* contained in your data) for a fieldterminator.  `BULK INSERT` is not very tolerant of embedded field terminators in the data.

Also, adding `FIRSTROW` to the statement does not skip field validation for the first row.  So you have to strip the headers before import, not just skip them.